# NSInvocation to delay calling of method causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, exc-bad-access, nsinvocation

I'm trying to display a message at the end of a game that shows whether or not the player has won.

Here is the relevant code:

```
BOOL yes = YES;
NSString *winMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You win!"];
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(endGameWithMessage:win:par:)]];
[inv setSelector:@selector(endGameWithMessage:win:par:)];
[inv setTarget:self];
[inv setArgument:&winMessage atIndex:2];
[inv setArgument:&yes atIndex:3]; //this is the win BOOL (0 and 1 are explained in the link above)
[inv setArgument:&parBool atIndex:4]; //this is the par BOOL
[inv performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
```

And here is the endGameWithMessage method signature:

```
- (void)endGameWithMessage:(NSString*)message win:(BOOL)win par:(BOOL)parBool
```

Although calling the code directly (which obviously won't allow a delay) like so works just fine, with the message showing up as expected and not causing any crashes:

```
[self endGameWithMessage:@"You win!" win:YES par:parBool];
```

Attempting to use NSInvocation results in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on the endGameWithMessage: method. Does this mean that I'm passing my values to the method invocation in the wrong manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two differences between those two pieces of code:

1. One uses the string literal `@"You win!"`, the other creates a new string object. String literals are allocated statically, and not memory-managed, so any incorrect memory management with the string parameter will affect the allocated object and not the string literal.
2. More importantly, the `NSInvocation` is invoked asynchronously, and you didn't ask the invocation to retain arguments with `[inv retainArguments];`. That means `self` and `winMessage` are not retained by the invocation, as it should in order to use them asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you for your support, especially for catching the lack of [inv retainArguments];. Your hypothesis was correct, adding a call to retainArguments after setting all of my arguments fixed my EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash because, like you said, the message was being sent with NULL arguments.